# hide / show certain markers depending on type attribute, google maps api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Im trying to hide / show markers on a google map depending on what 'type' the marker is.  I get the 'type' from JSON.  I'v searched the google docs (correct me if Im wrong) but it seems their example is not working, and does not explain how to remove / display markers according to attributes pulled from JSON. Here is their example. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove

I already have different markers depending on each type by using an if statement, but still I can't seem to select them to hide or show.  Below I'v written my jquery attempt, but it doesnt work.

```
        var type_1_icon = 'img/icon_1.png';
        var type_2_icon = 'img/icon_2.png';

        this.display_markers = function(){

        downloadUrl ("xml_output.php", function(data) {

        var xml = data.responseXML;

        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var site_name = markers[i] .getAttribute("site_name");
        var site_country = markers[i] .getAttribute("site_country");
        var site_state = markers[i] .getAttribute("site_state");
        var site_desc = markers[i] .getAttribute("site_desc");
        var type = markers[i] .getAttribute("type");
        var site_lat = markers[i] .getAttribute("site_lat");
        var site_lng = markers[i] .getAttribute("site_lng");
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
            parseFloat(markers[i] .getAttribute("site_lat")),
            parseFloat(markers[i] .getAttribute("site_lng")));

        var html =  "  /* HTML CONTENT */  ";

        if (type == 'type_1')
        {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: point,
                map: map,
                icon: type_1_icon
            });
        }
        else if (type == 'Type_2')
        {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                icon: type_2_icon
            });
        }
        else
        {
            var markericon ='images/icon_yellow.png';
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                icon: markericon
            });
        }

      var hidden_marker = false;

        function toggleGroup(type) {
          for (var i = 0; i < markers[type].length; i++) {
            var marker = markers[type][i];
            if (hidden_marker == true) {
              marker.setMap(map);
              hidden_marker = false;
            } else {
              marker.setMap(null);
              hidden_marker = true;
            }
          }
        }

        // UI Click buttons

        $('#fltr_btn').click(function(){
              toggleGroup('type_1');
        });

    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, InfoWindow, html);

    }
    });
```

Comment: site_dive_type looks wrong. If (marker.isHidden) looks wrong - you just set the map to null to hide a marker but that doesn't change its status to hidden it just means you can't see it.

Comment: Thanks for that Mark, I'v edited site_dive_type.  It was a mistake in the question.

Comment: You will need a variable to keep track of whether markers are visible or not yourself, then just set their map to null to hide them and set their map back to your correct map to show them again.

Comment: So is it all working now?

Comment: no i still have the same issue unfortunately

Comment: Your logic looks wrong. If hiddenmarker is false, you set it to false - which it already is.

Comment: Yes your right.  I'v updated it, but unfortunately still the same result.

Comment: Your toggleGroup() function is never going to toggle anything. It always sets hidden_marker to false at the beginning every time it is called and always does the same thing - namely turn on every odd numbered marker and turn off every even numbered marker. You need to store hidden_marker OUTSIDE toggleGroup and if it is true when you enter set it to false and if false when you enter, set it to true.

Comment: Yes your right, I updated it.  But I'm still getting the same result.  My console reads the error: cannot read the property 'length' of undefined.  It has a problem with the array?

Comment: You've only got a single hiddenmarker variable for the whole group, so you must want all markers in the group to be either hidden or visible - correct? If so, why do you change the hidden_marker every single time you change a single element of the array of markers?

Comment: correct, I want to hide all markers in the group. In other words, all markers of the same type.

Comment: [Classic "categories" example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_categories.html) (ported from the example on [this page of Mike Williams' v2 tutorial](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/categories.htm)